# Next dates using java

Tags: java, datetime

How can I calculate next dates using Java?

For example, if the user gives me the current date in a field like 2011-02-21, then I want to give back the same day of the month for the next two months: 2011-03-21, 2011-04-21.

Comment: What do you mean by "month by month"? Can you please provide sample data?

Comment: Next five date what ? Sounds ambiguous

Comment: excuse me, i was some fuzzy.
Example user give me the current date in a field like 20110221 and i will give back him next two months 20110321, 20110421.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Joda-Time](http://joda.sourceforge.net/):

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2005, 3, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    Period everyMonth= Period.months(1);

    DateTime dt1 = dt.plus(everyMonth);
    DateTime dt2 = dt1.plus(everyMonth);
    DateTime dt3 = dt2.plus(everyMonth);
    DateTime dt4 = dt3.plus(everyMonth);
    DateTime dt5 = dt4.plus(everyMonth);

    System.out.println(dt.toDate());
    System.out.println(dt1.toDate());
    System.out.println(dt2.toDate());
    System.out.println(dt3.toDate());
    System.out.println(dt4.toDate());
    System.out.println(dt5.toDate());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Sat Mar 26 00:00:00 CST 2005
Tue Apr 26 00:00:00 CDT 2005
Thu May 26 00:00:00 CDT 2005
Sun Jun 26 00:00:00 CDT 2005
Tue Jul 26 00:00:00 CDT 2005
Fri Aug 26 00:00:00 CDT 2005
```

Comment: I agree with @RealHowTo. There's no point in using an external library for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) of [YodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)?

```
new DateTime().plusDays(nDays)?
```

See also `plusMonths()`

Answer (score 1):

Use Calendar.add(...)

Here is the example:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());


    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

This prints:

```
Sat Dec 31 21:25:12 IST 2011
Sun Jan 01 21:25:12 IST 2012
```

(I just wanted to check that this really gives correct result when the next date is in the next year.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Calendar` like @AlexR said, you can use the `add(...)` method to add a point in the date.

**This:**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 21);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
System.out.println("user entered date:");
System.out.println(c.getTime());
System.out.println();
System.out.println("next five months:");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
}
```

**Prints out:**

```
user entered date:
Mon Feb 21 15:56:49 EST 2011

next five months:
Mon Mar 21 15:56:49 EDT 2011
Thu Apr 21 15:56:49 EDT 2011
Sat May 21 15:56:49 EDT 2011
Tue Jun 21 15:56:49 EDT 2011
Thu Jul 21 15:56:49 EDT 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Java [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), in particular the method [add](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: Not to be petty, but if you check the time I said it first ;-P

Answer (score 0):

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080613024301AAm7KbP